# 18 digit timestamp to Local Time

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, unix-timestamp, ntp, datetime-conversion

I came across Sq-lite database.I found our date time is stored in 18 digit time-stamp.

Please help me how to convert it to Local Time. (I tried to convert it(No.of milliseconds from 1900). But i did not get it.It shows 29 days difference. I added 29 days of milliseconds to time. But time output is wrong.My assumption is, it will be NTP time.)

Here i give 18-digit time-stamp and its equivalent date time.

### Time-Stamp                 Date-Time

362087070028927400         27-10-2014 15:06:57
362087302762879170         27-10-2014 15:22:06
362087302763135170         27-10-2014 15:22:06
362087302851460030         27-10-2014 15:22:06
362087302851716030         27-10-2014 15:22:06
362087302851716030         27-10-2014 15:22:06
362087305419799000         27-10-2014 15:22:16
362087307972777150         27-10-2014 15:22:26
362087310530875300         27-10-2014 15:22:36
362087313092045760         27-10-2014 15:22:46
362087315652448200         27-10-2014 15:22:56
362087318210802600         27-10-2014 15:23:06
362087320772741060         27-10-2014 15:23:16
362087323333655740         27-10-2014 15:23:26

Thanks

Comment: Do you not have any of the code which is producing those timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like it's based at 1970 (the Unix epoch) instead of 1900, with 256000000 "ticks" per second.

I haven't seen such a format before, but it seems to check out - for example, using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org):

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ToInstant(362087323333655740));
    }

    static Instant ToInstant(long value)
    {
        // We don't have to truncate to milliseconds, but it's simple for now...
        long millis = value / 256000;
        return Instant.FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(millis);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2014-10-27T09:53:26Z
```

... which would correspond to 2014-10-27T15:23:26 as the local time in India.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do i need to Nodatime library?

Comment: @MuniPrasad: Almost certainly not - but we have no idea what you're trying to *do* with this data... your question doesn't even talk about what language/platform you're using.

Comment: @JonSkeet.Yes absolutely, I don't need answer in particular language/Platform. I really need, the way to convert.

Comment: I'm curious about this. Is this a known "tick" system? @MuniPrasad can you say where this is coming from? (if not, i understand :) It's unlike anything i've seen before and i can't imagine anything that functions at this precision: it's down at the level of tens of picoseconds?

Comment: @TheSandman: It's not something I've seen before, but that doesn't necessarily mean much...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I did in Python that worked well for me (this is for 18-digit LDAP / Active Directory timestamps):

```
import datetime

def ad_timestamp(timestamp):
    if timestamp != 0:
        return datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=timestamp/10000000)
    return np.nan
```

So then if you need to convert a Pandas column:

```
df.lastLogonTimestamp = df.lastLogonTimestamp.fillna(0).apply(ad_timestamp)
```

Note: I needed to use `fillna` before using `apply`. Also, since I filled with 0's, I checked for that in the conversion function about, `if timestamp != 0`. Hope that makes sense. It's extra stuff but you may need it to convert the column in question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon Skeet.

I tried without NodaTime dll.

My code as In Vb.net;

```
Dim theDate As Date = New Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(CLng(lstUnixTime.Items(k) / 256000L))
Dim offsetAmount As TimeSpan = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(New Date(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
theDate += offsetAmount
```

Now I am getting Correct date.

Thanks for your valuable reply and answer.

Comment: You shouldn't add the offset like that - you can create a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Utc` and call `ToLocalTime` if you want. Or you could use Noda Time after all, which makes this sort of thing clearer, IMO :)

Comment: IS this OK :  Dim ticks As Long = CLng(lstUnixTime.Items(k) / 256000L)
            Dim UtcDate As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)
            UtcDate = UtcDate.AddMilliseconds(ticks)
            Dim theDate As New DateTime(UtcDate.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc)
            theDate.ToLocalTime()

Comment: Well why not just create the Unix epoch `DateTime` value with a kind of UTC to start with? That would make more sense, IMO.

Comment: You mean like this way :  Dim ticks As Long = CLng(formatting.Value / 256000L)
                Dim UtcDate As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
                UtcDate = UtcDate.AddMilliseconds(ticks)
                UtcDate.ToLocalTime()

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or just use Noda Time :)

Comment: Thanks. How can i use Noda-Time. Where can i download it.Is it Open License or i need to buy it?

Comment: Follow the link in my answer :) It's open source and free.

Comment: Only that it's very easy to get things wrong with `DateTime`: http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Answer (score 0):

for php

```
$dateLargeInt= "131424999530821857";
$secsAfterADEpoch = $dateLargeInt / (10000000);

$ADToUnixConvertor=((1970-1601) * 365.242190) * 86400; 
// unix epoch - AD epoch * number of tropical days * seconds in a day 
$unixTsLastLogon=intval($secsAfterADEpoch-$ADToUnixConvertor); 

// unix Timestamp version of AD timestamp
$lastlogon=date("d-m-Y", $unixTsLastLogon); // formatted date

echo $lastlogon;
```