# Skype persistent chat timestamp converstion

Tags: sql-server, skype, skype-for-business

I am building a tool which displays Skype persistent chat information along with participants information. For one of the requirement, I need to filter the tblComplianceParticipant table in a given date range.

I tried many different approaches to convert [tblComplianceParticipant](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558655.aspx).joinedAt column to human-readable format like 'yyyy-mm-dd', etc. but no luck so far.  Data in this column are 18 digit numbers, starting with "63" for example 636572952018269911 and 636455769656388453.

These values are also not in 'windows file time' format because https://www.epochconverter.com/ldap gives the future dates with above values.

I tried looking at @JonSkeet's answer on [18 digit timestamp to Local Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729302/18-digit-timestamp-to-local-time) but that is c# specific. I tried to replicate similar logic in SQL but no luck.

Is there any way to convert this 18 digit numbers to normal date format and perform where clause on it?

Comment: Your value is too large for a bigint. Are you sure that is the timestamp?

Comment: Yes, I have linked the MSDN link of table definition as well.

Comment: But the number you provided is way too large. There is something your missing or there is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Online converter which gives desired output: https://www.venea.net/web/net_ticks_datetime_converter#net_ticks_to_date_time_and_unix_timestamp_conversion

However, I was looking for underlying logic to convert it myself as I need to perform where clause on it in SQL server stored procedure.

Our Skype administrator provided me with a SQL function (fnDateToTicks) which was part of Skype database (mgc) (Earlier, I didn't have permission so could not see it). I am verifying with him whether it is an internal IP or standard solution by Microsoft so I can share it with the larger community.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing i can think is worth trying:

```
select CAST ([Timestamp Column]  as datetime)
```

Which will format it as yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00:000

This may work for SQL Server 2008 and onwards

Comment: I tried that and it throws an arithmetic overflow exception. Did you try above with sample values I have provided?

Comment: This answer is based on assumptions thats why you get a downvote. You should look into unix datestamps, but his int is too large